# Is there a threshold for declaring interest income from a foreign country?

Tags: united-states, international, tax-law

Assume the following situation:

- foreign national in the US
- working visa (e.g. H1-B)
- living permanently in the US, no other address, paying all taxes in the US
- savings account in home country (Europe)
- savings account incurs interest

Is there a threshold for declaring the interest incurred in a foreign country (income) when filing a US tax report?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no threshold.

You may be thinking of the threshold for reporting foreign accounts:

> In addition to reporting your worldwide income, you must also report on your U.S. tax return whether you have any foreign bank or investment accounts.

This is required if

> The aggregate value of all foreign financial accounts exceeds $10,000 at any time during the calendar year.

Source:

https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Income-from-Abroad-is-Taxable